# Ansible Nested variables and Jinja2 templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to figure out why my jinja2 template (and ansible for that matter) cannot find my variables in my inventory file.

Here is my inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    test05:
      ansible_host: 192.168.x.x
      filebeat:
        version: 7.15.2
        applog:
          - title: Separate Application Log Path with Tags
            type: log
            paths: 
              - /var/log/something/moresomething/current
            tags: '["something", "application"]'
          - title: Separate Application Log Path, with Tags, and "decode_json_fields" processor.
            type: log
            paths:
              - /var/log/something/moresomething/blah-shell.log
            tags: ["application", "something"]
            fields: ["message"]
            depth: 2
          - title: Separate Application Log Path, with Tags, and Multiline fields
            type: log
            paths:
              - /var/log/something/moresomething/production.log
            tags: ["application", "something"]
            multiline_type: pattern
            multiline_patern: 'Started'
            multiline_negate: true
            multiline_match: after
```

Then attempting to get the first title. I'm doing the following:

```
- name: debugging
  debug:
    var: filebeat.applog.title
```

when I run this I end up getting `filebeat.applog.title: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!` which I think is good since it doesn't know what title I want. So changing this to

```
- name: debugging
  debug:
    var: filebeat.applog.0.title
```

I end up getting what I want `filebeat.applog.0.title: Separate Application Log Path with Tags`. However, how do I use this in a jinja2 template?

I have the following for a template, I know I need to update this to loop through the different items in my inventory. That's a different problem on how to loop through this.

```
title: {{ filebeat.applog.title }}
  - type: {{ filebeat.applog.type }}
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - {{ filebeat.applog.path }}
   tags: {{ filebeat.applog.tags }}
{% if filebeat.applog.fields is defined %}
  processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: {{ filebeat.applog.fields }}
        max_depth: {{ filebeat.applog.depth }}
        target: {{ filebeat.applog.target | default "" }}
{% endif %}
{% if filebeat.applog.multiline_pattern  is defined %}
  multiline.type: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_type }}
  multiline.pattern: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_pattern }}
  multiline.negate: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_negate }}
  multiline.match: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_match }}
{% endif %}
```

each time I get the following, even when I do use `{{ filebeat.applog.0.logtitle }}` in the template:

```
fatal: [test05]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: |-
    AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'. String: title: {{ filebeat.applog.title }}
      - type: {{ filebeat.applog.type }}
        enabled: true
        paths:
          - {{ filebeat.applog.path }}
       tags: {{ filebeat.applog.tags }}
    {% if filebeat.applog.fields is defined %}
      processors:
        - decode_json_fields:
            fields: {{ filebeat.applog.fields }}
            max_depth: {{ filebeat.applog.depth }}
            target: {{ filebeat.applog.target | default "" }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if filebeat.applog.multiline_pattern  is defined %}
      multiline.type: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_type }}
      multiline.pattern: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_pattern }}
      multiline.negate: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_negate }}
      multiline.match: {{ filebeat.applog.multiline_match }}
    {% endif %}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong since this the first time doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the template you have should either:

- have a `for` loop to iterate over `filebeat.applog`

OR

- reference *n'th* element of `filebeat.applog`

---

Aside from that, there are some errors like below:

1.

> `target: {{ filebeat.applog.target | default "" }}`

This is the main one, and this is what the error message is complaining about, i.e. `got 'string'`. The correct usage for `default` filter is `{{ some_variable | default("") }}`.

2.

> `{% if filebeat.applog.multiline_pattern  is defined %}`

In the inventory this variable is mis-spelled, i.e. `multiline_patern` (missing one "t"). Fix this in your inventory.

3.

> when I do use `{{ filebeat.applog.0.logtitle }}` in the template

This should be `{{ filebeat.applog.0.title }}` to work.

---

Considering the above fixes, a template that loops over `filebeat.applog` such as below should work:

```
{% for applog in filebeat.applog %}
title: {{ applog.title }}
  - type: {{ applog.type }}
    enabled: true
    paths: {{ applog.paths }}
    tags: {{ applog.tags }}
{% if applog.fields is defined %}
  processors:
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: {{ applog.fields }}
        max_depth: {{ applog.depth }}
        target: {{ applog.target | default("") }}
{% endif %}
{% if applog.multiline_pattern is defined %}
  multiline.type: {{ applog.multiline_type }}
  multiline.pattern: {{ applog.multiline_pattern }}
  multiline.negate: {{ applog.multiline_negate }}
  multiline.match: {{ applog.multiline_match }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```